# Are the RAW type variables immutable in PL/SQL code?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Are the `RAW` type variables immutable in PL/SQL code? I mean can I alter specific byte of `RAW` type variable just in place without memory copying?

Of course we have `UTL_RAW` package with some routines appropriate for spec byte altering but it looks like all of them copy variable instance memory:

`UTL_RAW.BIT_AND` `UTL_RAW.BIT_OR` `UTL_RAW.OVERLAY`

Also this question is closely linked to effective string concatenation problem. For example in Java strings are immutable too and we have the StringBuilder for this task. 
I've not found clear info in Oracle docs on this. After some googling[1] the answer **looks** like: **Yes. The RAW type variables are immutable in PL/SQL code as well as strings are.** Is it really true? It would be better to have more explanation and history of this question.

References:

1. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:10445025326812#followup-76860752200038

Comment: Not sure I understand the purpose of this question. You can certainly update RAW variables, just like any other variables. The semantics are the same. The exception regarding NOCOPY parameters apply the same, as well - but this is not applicable to any of the functions in UTL_RAW, as far as I can see. Why do you need to alter a specific bit of a RAW variable without memory copying?

Comment: The purpose in general is clearing internal behavior of the PL\SQL machine. Also there is practical problem of efficiency of working with strings\raw's. We will get high memory traffic if we will do huge amount of  operations on them. For example concatination. Why does this confuse me? Because of Java and what StringBuilder exists for in it. It looks like we have problem and solution in Java and in PL\SQL we have  only problem.

Comment: Still not sure what your problem is. If performance of pure PL/SQL is an issue, then using NOCOPY, and/or perhaps native compiled PL/SQL may be avenues to explore. Still, `RAW` variables are not an issue in themselves; you are presumably using them to solve a problem - what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: can you build some test cases? What is so poor on plsql string manipulation?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing in PL/SQL as altering a specific subpart of the memory allocated to a variable. If it is a function (as is the case with the said `utl_raw` routines), it always returns a new instance of a value. If it is a procedure with an `in out nocopy` parameter, it **might** work on the [reference to the argument](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS659), not on its copy, but still, the actual work inside the procedure involves copying values, not working in the same memory. (Well, OK, this does not apply to LOBs, but that's not what you've asked about.)

PL/SQL is a procedural language on top of SQL. It is designed to allow the SQL to be used procedurally, it is not designed to be superfast, supereffective. If you need to go as far as altering bytes directly in memory, you may want to use C or assembler.

Comment: Hi, do you have a reference for _If it is a procedure with a in out nocopy parameter, it works on the reference to the argument, not on its copy, but still, the actual work inside the procedure involves copying values, not working in the same memory._?

Comment: In addition to @FlorinGhita it would be nice to have some reference for *If it is a function (as is the case with the said utl_raw routines), it always returns a new instance of a value* . This is stated in the question without doc ref too. Your answer brings not much **new** information about the topic.

Comment: I don't know what more can I tell you? There's simply a common sense which is telling me that returning values from functions simply involves memory copying, as is always the case with basic `variable := variable` assignments.

Comment: @FlorinGhita, Oracle doc reference added.